# HTML/CSS Age verification

Tags: css, html, web-deployment-project

I'm relatively new to website development and haven't yet moved onto java script or PHP. I want to create a very basic age verification page that allows entry into a mock website for my portfolio that i can show to any potential employers for when i start my apprenticeship.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this input which does not require any scripts:

```
<input type="number" name="age" min="18">
```

Refer to the following link for more insight:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp